# Uncertainty principle type inequality with delta function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

This is a bit of a broad question but I'm wondering if there is a type of uncertainty principle that describes the integrals
$$ \int f(y)g_\epsilon(y)dy, \quad \int f(y)g_\epsilon(y)^2dy. $$
(I assume $f, g$ are positive for simplicity.) I noticed that when $g_\epsilon(y)$ is an approximation to $\delta_0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$, e.g. let's say $g_\epsilon$ is the heat kernel, then $\int f(y)g_\epsilon(y)dy \rightarrow f(0)$ as expected but numerically it seems $\int f(y)g_\epsilon(y)^2dy \rightarrow \infty$. More generally if $g_\epsilon \rightarrow \delta_0$ can anything be said about $g_\epsilon^2$?

I'm also not sure if the first integral should be squared as well to keep the normalisation the same, and I've also tried to replace $g_\epsilon$ with bump functions (e.g. $g_\epsilon = 1$ on $B_{\epsilon/2}(0)$ and $g_\epsilon \equiv 0$ away from $B_\epsilon(0)$) but I don't think I get any meaningful results.

I'd be interested in any results but I'm interested in particular to know if there is any lower bound on $(\int fg_\epsilon)(\int fg_\epsilon^2)$ or $(\int fg_\epsilon)^2(\int fg_\epsilon^2)$ for instance (given in terms of $f$). I know the uncertainty principle is usually stated in terms of Fourier transform so I'm not sure if it's reasonable to expect any useful estimates so any counterexamples to this idea would be great too.